# If valid forms must start with a symbol than what is ((lambda (a) (+ 1 a)) 1)

Tags: lambda, common-lisp

I've read and understood that not all s-exps are necessarily valid forms. In particular, valid *list forms* must start with a symbol that will be evaluated as being either:

- a function name
- a macro name
- a built-in form

If that's the case, then what happens in the reader and evaluator when I type this:

```
((lambda (a) (+ 1 a)) 1)
-> 2
```

The first element of that list is not a symbol, it's a list. So how come it evaluates? Is the reader doing something special here?

Comment: See hyperspec [3.1.2.1.2 Conses as Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm).

Comment: It's a macro that gets expanded to `#'(lambda...)` and it is the only exception to the rule since unlike an arbitrary expression every aspect is known at compile time.